# How to get the shape of a lake with the HERE-API

Tags: android, here-api

I'm building a rowing-related Android app with the here-api and would like to compute the (closest) distance to the shoreline to warn a rower if he is too close (which is not allowed on some lakes). I found a way to [get the are for cities or postalcode](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/example-geocode-retrieve-shape-area.html) but not for a location (with "LocationType": "lake").

Here obviously has this data, but is there a way to get it from them?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion.

HERE-API supports that shape data.
please see below documents.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/resource-layers.html

Below request will list layers.

```
https://pde.api.here.com/1/doc/layers.html?app_id={{app_id}}&app_code={{app_code}}
```

And there is some layers you are interested in 
especially Layers CARTO_POLY_DO1 to CARTO_POLY_DO5 have polygon shape data.

Also below request list the detail information of the layer.

```
https://pde.api.here.com/1/doc/layer.html?layer=CARTO_POLY_DO3&app_id={{app_id}}&app_code={{app_code}}
```

I hope this help!

Comment: How could I pass a LocationID for a specific lake?